# how to simplify this expresion $a^2+ab+-a-b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$a^2+ab-a-b$$

I tried simplifying by taking the $a$ out and I got the expression
$a(a+b-1)-b$.
But that doesn't seem enough I also tried:
There must be $z$ and $w$ that if we look at it as a $ax^2+bx+c$, then
$zw=ac$ and $z+w=b$.
But then I can't seem to figure out what the $c$ is in this specific expression.

Comment: $(a-1)(a+b) = a^2+ab-a-b$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

We have
$$(a^2+ab)-(a+b)$$

What factor can you take out from the first bracket?

Comment: you need not say more, much obliged.

Comment: You're welcome! :-)